# Notifications Configuration in S/4Hana 1610

Tags: sap-fiori

I have configured Notifications as per [blog](https://blogs.sap.com/2017/02/13/leading-s4hana-ux-notification-center-part-1-activation/) in our S4Hana 1610(Embedded Architecture) Landscape.

But while checking bgRFC Monitor (Transaction sbgrfcmon), it is showing **Data Not Available**

[image: bgRFC Monitor]

Although I have

1.Created an RFC destination name IWNGW_BGRFC with transfer protocol Classic with bgRFC.

2.Created an RFC destination IWNGW_BEP_OUT_BGRFC for the background RFC queue with queue prefix set to Q.

3.Registered the IWNGW_BEP_OUT_BGRFC destination for background processing by creating a queue.

4.Supervisor destination BGRFC_SUPERVISOR already existed in the system.

Please guide.

Regards,

Rehan Sayed

Additional Attachments :

[image: bgRFC Monitor]

[image: Demo Notification]

[image: Registration]

[image: Manage Notification]

[image: Activation of Push Notification]

[image: Testing Workflow]

Answer (score 0):

In transaction SM59 you can run a “Connection Test” on these RFC-destinations.
Is this working?

When you call transaction “sbgrfcmon”, which parameters do you provide at the selection screen?
Maybe a screenshot could help.

I think “sbgrfcmon” is a Monitor, where you will only see entries which are in error state or queued up, waiting for processing.
If you have no or only limited activity without any errors, you will be lucky, to see here any entries.
Please see also [bgRFC Monitor](https://help.sap.com/saphelp_nwpi711/helpdata/en/48/927c5caa6b17cee10000000a421937/content.htm)

What happens if you produce some activity in the development system (maybe with errors) and keep refreshing “sbgrfcmon”?

Comment: “Connection Test” on these RFC-destinations is successful.I have attached the bgRFC Monitor screenshot above.If I  run transaction /IWNGW/BEP_DEMO to send a demonstration notification it appears in Launchpad(PFA) but if I create new Purchase Order,it reflects in SBWP transaction and My Inbox App but its notification is not displayed in Launchpad.

Comment: Have you followed also the steps in [Leading S/4HANA UX – Notification Center – Part 2 – Providing Notifications](https://blogs.sap.com/2017/02/14/leading-s4hana-ux-notification-center-part-2-providing-notifications/) ?
Especially the steps about “Activate the Task Provider”, where you define “SAP_BUSINESS_WORKFLOW” as notification provider ?
At the end of this blog, there is also a paragraph about “Testing Workflow Notifications”.
Does this work ?

Comment: I have followed the steps as per the mentioned link and “Testing Workflow Notifications” works(PFA for the same).

Comment: Is this issue still open?
If you create new Purchase Order, it reflects in SBWP transaction and My Inbox App but its notification is not displayed in Launchpad?

Answer (score 0):

The issue is resolved,since our system's SAP_BASIS component was on SP000 and it does not detect workflow maintained in SWF_PUSH_NOTIF1 transaction with Customizing set to 'X'.

Hence maintained workflow in SWF_PUSH_NOTIF1 transaction without Customizing and notification worked.

Regards,

Sayed